# How to set active GPU to only be NVIDIA GPU

Tags: debian, nvidia

My laptop has a GTX1650 Ti, but it doesn't use it, instead defaulting to the integrated CPU. I know about bumblebee and optirun, but I don't want to use that, I'd rather change the default GPU to be the GTX1650. On a previous laptop I owned, I was able to change the default GPU, and I'd like to do the same thing here. I do not care about battery life, I only use it plugged in. I'm using the Asus FX706LI with Debian Sid.

Comment: If you have the proper Nvidia drivers installed then simply open Nvidia X Server Settings, change the profile to "High performance (Nvidia)" and reboot. Done. Why is this even a question? I'm assuming you did it before? *On a previous laptop I owned, I was able to change the default GPU*